# How to transfer common stocks from a broker in France to a broker in the United States?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, brokerage, france

I have some stocks in a brokerage account in France. How can I move them to a brokerage account based in the United States?

Comment: You're not the first person to want to do this so contact your broker. They will let you know solutions exist.

Comment: I've had it done- it was pretty easy. I think I just told the US broker that the transfer was going to take place, and then filled out a few forms with the French broker (proving it was me, etc.). They took care of it.

Comment: @BobT Thanks, interesting 1) in which currency(ies) did you purchase and sell these stocks? 2) did you have to pay any transfer fees?

Comment: In what way would currency matter? You are moving stocks, not money.

Comment: I don't believe I paid any transfer fees... I didn't sell the stocks, so the currency was irrelevant.

Comment: @BobT Thanks, if you were to sell the  stocks, would  the currency when selling be the same as the currency that you used to purchase them in France?

Comment: They are listed in US exchanges so currency would be dollars... I imagine that if a stock were only listed on an exchange in France then you'd need to sell in that exchange and receive francs...